# Поддержка языков на yii?

Tags: yii, кодировка

В общем, в первый раз работаю с данным фреймворком, да и с фреймворками дело имею впервые. И вот самый первый вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы распознавалась кириллица?
Ато меню делаю русскоязычное - выходят кракозябры =)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в кодировке файлов. Проверьте, чтобы все файлы были в кодировке utf-8, база была в кодировке utf-8, используются строковые функции для utf-8. Проблема не во фреймворке, yii здесь совершенно не причем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в корень проекта файл .htaccess  со следующим содержимым: AddDefaultCharset utf8

Локально это решит проблему, т.е. данного проекта.

П.С. В конфиге еще есть 'charset'=>'utf8'. Вроде так. Ну перекодировать все файлы в utf8 without BOM. Под виндой это несколько проблемно. Именно найти утилитку для рекурсивного перекодирования всей папки. В линухе из терминала одной строкой.

Answer (score 4):

Yii здесь не при чем. У вас просто с кодировкой что-то не то. Возможно указан атрибут charset, который не соответствует кодировке файлов. Файлы должны быть сохранены в той же кодировке, которая указана в теге charset вашей html страницы.

Comment: ох. слушайте! точно.. вот мозги не варят после учебы. сталкивалась же уже с этим. спасибо. сейчас буду переделывать=)